# Change VS2013 Standard properties in windows forms designer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer, visual-studio-designer

we use VS2013 in our company and when creating forms with the designer the standard of the autoscalemode is "font". We have a lot of problems with that - we need "none". Sometimes developers forget to change that.

Is it possible to change the standardvalue of this property?

thanks

Comment: You don't need None, it is *very* incompatible with UI that displays text.  Doing the wrong thing is supposed to take extra effort, forces you to properly solve the problem.

Comment: it is necessary for us to use none. our software is doing the rest. (Layouting, resourcemanagement.....). If its basically wrong - there is no reason for "none". But it is there, so it makes sense sometimes to use it, like in our case.

Comment: VS allows you to create your own item templates.  File + Export Template.  Inheritance is also well supported.